# Computer boots into grub rescue mode

Tags: grub2

I recently dual booted my computer to have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 on it. I later decided that I didn't want Ubuntu so in Win 7 I went to disk management and deleted 2 volumes that were not their before I made an Ubuntu partition and then when I restarted my computer all that came up on the screen was 
error no such partition
grub rescue>

What does this mean?
What do I do to either boot into Windows or Linux?
Any help is appreciated I am very new to Linux
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Boot the windows installation disk,click on Windows recovery option and then select command prompt.Run the following commands in that command prompt,

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr
bootrec.exe /FixBoot
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

OR

Download [`boot-repair`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) live disk.Make a bootable boot-repair live usb,change the boot-order in bios to usb.Once the live disk was boot up click on the option `Recommende Repair`.It will reinstall your grub.